# ansible does not see hosts (unreachable)

Tags: ansible

I have recently installed ansible

```
demaunt@demaunt-pc:~$ ansible --version
ansible 2.3.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

I have added 2 lines into: **/etc/ansible/hosts**

```
[local]
192.168.1.102
```

and changed uncommented 1 line in **ansible.cfg**:

```
# uncomment this to disable SSH key host checking
host_key_checking = False
```

Still when I do:

```
ansible all -m ping
192.168.1.102 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.102' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

1) Why my localhost is unreachable

2) Why this program is so smart that it tries to connect via ssh even when this option was disabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To define localhost and use `local` connection instead of ssh, define hosts as follows:

```
[local]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

This way we define `local` group with `localhost` host with `local` connection.

Answer (score 1):

The option `host_key_checking = False` does not mean Ansible will not connect to hosts. It's an option related to the ssh option `StrictHostKeyChecking` (see the ssh_config man page).

Ansible needs to log into the host to perform the `ping`. Your local host at IP 192.168.1.102 is probably not running the sshd daemon, or some other issue is preventing the ssh login.

Suggest you review the documentation at http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html.